# Select sum of payments in period where first payment was made in that period

Tags: mysql, select

I have table of payments 'user_id - created - price'. 
I need to calculate sum of all payments made in period 14-16 of March where first payment was made in the same period

The best solution I came by is

```
 SELECT user_id, SUM(price/100) FROM payment WHERE
 (DATE(created) BETWEEN '2014-03-14' AND '2014-03-16')
 AND (MIN(created) BETWEEN '2014-03-14 00:00:01' AND '2014-03-16 23:59:59')
 GROUP BY user_id
```

but I got "Invalid use of group function"

Update:
This request solved my problem

```
SELECT p.user_id, SUM(p.price/100) FROM payment p WHERE
(DATE(created) BETWEEN '2014-03-14' AND '2014-03-16')
AND (SELECT MIN(DATE(created)) FROM payment WHERE user_id = p.user_id) BETWEEN '2014-03-14' AND '2014-03-16'
GROUP BY p.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `MIN()` function in where clause,you need to use `HAVING` to filter on aggregate functions you can rewrite your query as below

```
 SELECT user_id, SUM(price/100) 
 FROM payment 
 WHERE
 created BETWEEN '2014-03-14 00:00:00' AND '2014-03-16 23:59:59'
 GROUP BY user_id
 HAVING MIN(created) BETWEEN '2014-03-14 00:00:00' AND '2014-03-16 23:59:59'
```

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. I need only payments from users who paid for the first time in the same period (BETWEEN '2014-03-14' AND '2014-03-16'). Your request will return all payments during this period

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid this request doesn't work correctly. I checked on the first user_id in output and the first payment created by this user was in Feb

Comment: Please add sample dataset and your desired result set in your question that would be easier  or better to provide http://sqlfiddle.com/ demo

Comment: Thank you very much, but I solved my problem by modification of my initial request (see update to my post)